# Trying to trouble Object required error in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, compiler-errors, vba

I got this problem.  I have a form that retrieves a table data using the forms' record source property. When the form's opened, I set its record source property to a module's public method RetrieveMembers.  Here's the code below.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
'set Form's record source property to retrieve a Members table
Me.RecordSource = mod_JoinMember.RetrieveMembers

End Sub

'mod_JoinMember Class
Public Function RetrieveMembers() As String

Dim strSQL As String
Set strSQL = "SELECT tbl_Member.Title, tbl_Member.Gender, tbl_Member.LastName, 
tbl_Member.DateofBirth, tbl_Member.Occupation, tbl_Member.PhoneNoWork, 
tbl_Member.PhoneNoHome, tbl_Member.MobileNo, tbl_Member.Email, 
tbl_Member.Address, tbl_Member.State, tbl_Member.Postcode FROM tbl_Member;"
RetrieveMembers = strSQL

End Function
```

**Object required** error is thrown.

I couldn't comprehend this compile error.  I see no wrong with my code since recordsource is a String type property.  And my module's function Retrievemembers is returning a String value.

Why is it that it's not satisfied with this?

Comment: what line is the error thrown on? (I suspect in code not shown...)

Comment: It's thrown at the Public Function RetrieveMembers as String line. Just a little info - while the database application is a MS Access 2003, I'm running MS Access 2007 software on my laptop. FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

I fixed it.  The reason was because String is not really an Object to begin with.  So the 'Set' keyword is not needed - since you don't need to explicitly declare String-type objects anyway!

All good now!

Comment: +1 Well spotted, I completely missed that : )  Worth mentioning that you could shorten your code by removing strSQL and just setting RetrieveMembers to the SQL immediately.

Comment: @MattDonnan: Yes I could do that I supposed.  Saves me the headache of troubleshooting later on.  Moreover, I didn't know Record Source is a string type property at the time this problem first occurred hence had to write long code, thinking it could take a recordset object... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with a class module I think you will need to use:

```
Public Property Get RetrieveMembers() As String
```

Rather than:

```
Public Function RetrieveMembers() As String
```

Comment: Matt.  I tried that.  But it doesn't work.  The errors keeps throwing at the function method line ie Public Function RetrieveMembers() as String.

Comment: @AW-GWTF899 Have you tried running it with an Access 03 runtime rather than 07, there are compatibility issues.